# Extending the Content Query WebPart

Tags: sharepoint, moss

I'm wanting to have some data displayed on a SharePoint page which is essentially a Content Query WebPart, but with a few small changes:

- Filter on a dynamic date
- Paged Results

Is it possible to do the modifications by extending the existing one or is there a component out there which will do that?

Answer (score 2):

I also had a project that needed a Content Query web part with dynamic filtering. My solution was to extend the existing one (ContentByQueryWebPart class) similar to [this blog post](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2008/02/18/Subclassing-the-Content-Query-Web-Part-Adding-Dynamic-Filtering.aspx) written by Andrew Connell.

My solution also included a custom "filter" webpart for dynamically changing the filter value to use in the extended Content query web part. This "filter" web part was basically a dropdown control that used javascript to reload the page with parameters added to the querystring. It worked perfectly.

I didn't implement any paging functionality to my custom Content Query web part, so I haven't tried this myself. After some searching I found [this blog post](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/paging-content-query-web-part/) by Waldek Mastykarz. He shows an example of how to implement paging by extending the Content Query web part. He also uses the queyrsting approach for passing parameter and I don't see any issues with integrating both paging and dynamic filtering in an extended Content Query web part.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Data Form or Data View webpart. I believe it is more flexible in this regard. you may need to [build a custom data source](http://jamestsai.net/Blog/post/How-to-query-cross-site-lists-in-DataFormWebPart-Part-1-Build-your-own-data-source-for-DataFormWebPart.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source project on CodePlex that extends the Content Query Web Part:

[Enhanced Content Query Web Part](http://www.codeplex.com/ECQWP)